# What is the most efficient way to get all the fields of all files in an Azure storage account?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-log-analytics

I need to see all the possible fields/columns in my storage account and how many times they appear in each container. Example:
| Containers | Field1        |Field2|Field3|
| -------- | -------------- |----|-|
| Container1| 45|23|100|
| Container2| 46|2|101|
(field1 appeared in 45 files in container1, while field1 appeared in 46 files in container2)

The current solution is really slow and simply doesn't do the job for our huge storage account, since it lists all the blobs then reads each one to get the columns. We are using pyspark in Databricks, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing this using the Azure Portal, something like Log Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using **Azure Synapse** to do an SQL query over Blob in an Azure Storage Account.  Azure Synapse is an enterprise analytics service that accelerates time to insight across data warehouses and big data systems. Azure Synapse brings together the best of SQL technologies used in enterprise data warehousing, Spark technologies used for big data, Data Explorer for log and time series analytics, Pipelines for data integration and ETL/ELT, and deep integration with other Azure services such as Power BI, CosmosDB, and AzureML.

See [Analyze data in a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-storage) for details.